# Data Comparison in R

Tags: r, excel, validation, comparison

I am trying to compare two Excel files (same number of columns, but sometimes different number of rows).

I imported the Excel files to `data1` and `data2` respectively.

```
library(dataCompareR)
comparedata <- rCompare(data1, data2)
summary(comparedata)
saveReport(comparedata, reportName = 'Comparison Result')
```

All goes well, but I have three challenges:

1. The Sample row data is set to 5. **How can I increase that to the actual different row that the summery comes up with?**
2. **How can I ask the primary key in the result as it only shows the two matching columns?**
3. Sometimes the numbers of the row don't match, and the data gets off. **Can I set up a primary comparison key instead of row to row?**

Comment: welcome to SO. have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you have got a very specific problem, please make a reproducible example with example data, so that we can understand better what your question is. Unfortunately, we are humans, not oracles.